# Как узнать версию ruby в RoR проекте?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Открываю я значит какой нибудь RoR проект. Как мне понять, какую версию ruby он использует? Или под какую версию его создали предыдущие разработчики?

Answer (score 1):

Хорошей практикой является указание версии руби в `Gemfile`. Кроме того, она может быть указана в файле `.ruby-version`, это помогает rvm и rbenv автоматически переключать версию при переходе в папку проекта

Answer (score 0):

Установите RVM и попробуйте разные версии под свой проект.

Установить нужную версию Ruby.
rvm install 1.7.2 
rvm install 2.7

Посмотреть установленные версии Ruby.
rvm list

Переключится на другую версию Ruby.
rvm use ruby 2.2.2

Посмотреть какая версия Ruby работает по умолчанию.
rvm rubies

Comment: Но я всё же ищу способ узнать версию не методом тыка

Comment: @MaksimBelousov Если не был использован rvm то это сделать не возможно. Если есть файл с расширением .rvmrc то там вы найдёте всю необходиму информацию о проекте.